# PHP Method for JSON data with Python requests.post

Tags: php, python, json

I am trying to pass a complicated dict into a Python requests.

```
dict={
 'form':'parse_category',
 'category':{
  'category':1,
  'text':'cat',
  'plural_text':'cats'
 },
 'sources':[1,2,3,4,5,6]
}

category=requests.post('http://localhost/trigger.php',json=dict)
print category.text
```

I would like to get a nice multidimensional **$_POST** variable on `trigger.php`

Desired result:

```
$_POST=[
 'form'=>'parse_category',
 'category'=>[
  'category'=>1,
  'text'=>'cat',
  'plural_text'=>'cats'
 ],
 'sources'=>[1,2,3,4,5,6]
];
```

I learned that I need to use `json=dict` or some type of json encoded variable. What method do I use to get the JSON data on the PHP side? $_POST and $_GET return empty.

Comment: Did you ever discover how to do this?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I answered my question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a JSON parameter:

```
import json
category=requests.post('http://localhost/trigger.php',params={'json':json.dumps(array)})
```

Then decode the json on the php side:

```
if(isset($_GET['json'])){$_POST=json_decode($_GET['json']);}
```

Comment: this is incorrect. You sent a POST request, but received a GET.